# ASP DataConnectivity Error

Tags: database, iis, asp-classic, connectivity

I am a Student and ASP is my subject this year. I am trying to do the Database Connectivity for the First time. It gave me this Error while i was connecting my ASP file with MSAccess.
Code:

```
<% 
Dim objConn, strConn, objRS
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConn = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE =" & _
 "C:\demo.accdb"
objConn.Open strConn
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open "Student", objConn, 2, 2
objRS.AddNew
objRS("idnum") = Request.Form("idnum")
objRS("firstname") = Request.Form("firstname")
objRS("lastname") = Request.Form("lastname")
objRS.Update
objRS.close
%>
```

**The Above code Gives the Following Error:*
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
/MyWeb/choice1.asp, line 12*
.. I also tried doing this..
..
..

```
Dim objConn, strConn, objRS
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConn = "DSN=Stud"
objConn.Open strConn
```

and it gives me the same error.
My Database name is demo.accdb
My Table name is Student.
ApplicationPool Settings for IIS is set to "true" for using Windows 32bit.
I have also installed OLEDB ACE 12.

Please help as am totally in mess.. All I want is to insert a record in an Access Database.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the fields in your table 'student'? check if you have spelled the fieldnames like idnum correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error has nothing to do with your connection, setup, IIS settings, or anything esoteric, and everything to do with what columns exist (or rather, don't exist) in the recordset you're opening.

What is in line 12 of your code? (In the snippet you've posted, line 12 is the "lastname" field, but I don't know if that's true for your actual code.) Check the setup of the `Student` table: did you spell that column name correctly? If the table column is `LastN`, then your code should have `objRS("LastN") = Request.Form("LastName")`<sup>1</sup>, not `objRS("LastName")...`. Thankfully, neither VBScript nor SQL are case-sensitive, so you don't need to be anal, but you do need to spell things correctly.

Note that it may help you "see" what you're doing better if you write an explicit `SELECT` statement to return just the columns (and rows) you want, instead of opening the entire table. Also, when you're working with actual databases (which tend to have many thousands or even millions of records, rather than the half a dozen you probably have in your test database), opening entire tables is A Very Bad Idea. Well, unless you *like* timeout errors.

```
objRS.Open "SELECT TOP 0 id, firstname, lastname FROM Student", objConn, 2, 2
```

(Since all you're doing is adding a row, you don't actually need to return any records; hence the `TOP 0`.<sup>2</sup>)

<sub><sup>1</sup> All you "OMG! Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection!!1!" types can insert your customary rant here.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> It's been a while since I've worked with Access; if it chokes on `TOP 0` with no `ORDER BY` clause, try `SELECT ... WHERE 1 = 2`.</sub>

Comment: @YusufSM: if my answer was helpful to you, please consider marking it as "accepted". It'll get both of us some reputation points, but more importantly, it will tell the system that this question is answered.